# node.js asynchronous steps in forEach loop not running in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

Asynchronous JS hurts my brain... ;)

```
1  const aoSpecialInstrumentTSLMgrs = [];
2  await asInstruments.forEach(async sInstrument => {
3      const oInstrument = await CInstrument.fpoGet(sInstrument);
4      const oSpecialInstrument = new CSpecialInstrument(this, oInstrument, oTimeframe);
5      const oSpecialInstrumentTSLMgr = new CSpecialInstrumentTSLMgr(oSpecialInstrument);
6      await oSpecialInstrumentTSLMgr.fInit();
7      aoSpecialInstrumentTSLMgrs.push(oSpecialInstrumentTSLMgr);
8  });
9  // then more code here.
```

I need this to run as if it were synchronous.  Hence the asyncs/awaits, of course. By the time I reach line 9, I need the `aoSpecialInstrumentTSLMgrs` array to be populated with what's supposed to be pushed into it in line 8...

But that's not happening.

When I step through it in my debugger -- even with a breakpoint on every line of the above code in case I'm pressing the wrong buttons as I step through or something -- it goes to line 3, then steps into the `CInstr….fpoGet()` as expected. That's an async function by necessity. It steps through that function, also as expected. But then when it steps out of that function it goes straight to line 9 and skips all of lines 4 - 8.

I believe it's because it's asynchronous code inside a loop -- I've probably got some asyncs/awaits in the wrong places?

How do I get it to run the above lines in the order they would if everything was synchronous -- ie. run lines 4-7 (as many times as there are `asInstruments` of course) before it hits line 9?

And why doesn't the above work?

Thanks!

(PS. This is forEach instead of map because it's actually populating a few arrays inside the forEach not just one, but I've simplified it down to just one, for the question.  So even if array.map is part of a solution here that might fail me. I believe I need it to be forEach.  In case that makes any difference.)

Comment: Did you try `for await ... of` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: [`forEach`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined`. `undefined` cannot be awaited. Use [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Promise.all`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or a similar method.